# How to persist data in a service on refresh in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, refresh

I'm creating a new multi-use website for a new brand my company is launching in a few weeks. We use a WordPress backend and via the WP REST API, are now able to uncouple the system and use NodeJS/Express/AngularJS for our front end and middleware applications.

Currently, when I load the landing page, an HTTP GET Request is made to WordPress for all of the relevant posts for our front page. This data is then passed to a service to be used across controllers.

So, the initial set up is this:

landingController

```
    angular
     .module('glossy')
     .controller('LandingController', LandingController)

    LandingController.$inject = ['featuredService', 'sharedPostsService'];

    function LandingController(featuredService, sharedPostsService){

     // Set up view model (vm) variables
     var vm = this;
     vm.featured = [];

     // Call this function on state 'home' load
     activate();

     // Calls getFeatured function and prints to console
     function activate(){
       return getFeatured()
         .then(function(){
           console.log('GET Featured Posts');
       });
     }

     // Calls the featuredService then stores response clientside for rendering
     function getFeatured(){
       return featuredService.getFeatured()
       .then(function(data){
          vm.featured = data;
          sharedPostsService.setPosts(data);
          return vm.featured;
        });
     }
   }
```

Factory for HTTP Request

```
    angular
     .module('glossy')
     .factory('featuredService', featuredService)

    featuredService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function featuredService($http){
      return {
       getFeatured: getFeatured
      };

      // Performs HTTP request then calls success or error functions
      function getFeatured(){
        return $http.get('/api/posts')
        .then(getFeaturedComplete)
        .catch(getFeaturedFailed);

        // Returns response data
        function getFeaturedComplete(response){
          return response.data;
        }

        // Prints error to console
        function getFeaturedFailed(error) {
          console.log('HTTP Request Failed for getFeatured: ' + error.data);
        }
      }
   }
```

Service that holds data from factory

```
    angular
     .module('glossy')
     .factory('sharedPostsService', sharedPostsService)

    function sharedPostsService(){

      var listPosts = [];

      return {
        setPosts: function(posts){
          listPosts = posts;
        },
        getPosts: function(){
          return listPosts;
        }
      };
    }
```

Now, when a user clicks on a post on the landing page, she is taken to a page that displays on the article that she clicked on, which works. However, if she refreshes this page, all the data is gone. Calling the service results in an empty object.

Post controller

```
   angular
     .module('glossy')
     .controller('PostController', PostController)

   PostController.$inject = ['$window', '$filter', '$stateParams', 'sharedPostsService'];

   function PostController($window, $filter, $stateParams, sharedPostsService){

     var vm = this;
     vm.postsList = sharedPostsService.getPosts();
     vm.postTitle = $stateParams.title;
     vm.thisPost = filterPosts();

     function filterPosts() {
       return $filter('filter')(vm.postsList, vm.postTitle);
     };
   }
```

How do I set this up to ensure that the data persists through refresh? I looked into using localStorage but everything I found said it involved stringifying data and storing it in key value pairs?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at alaSQL. It seems like the best of the bunch for papering over the fact that sqlLite was abandoned in favor of localStorage in many environments.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship – I'm not sure I need to create an in-browser database, all I need to do is save the single post that I'm trying to display so that it's data isn't removed upon refresh. Then, whenever I open a new post, the previous can be removed and new one saved, and so on.

Comment: My philosophy is never trap yourself in a bubble that's hard to expand when developing. It's not that much harder to code for the idea that requirements are very likely to change than to code for the idea that they won't. In many cases it's easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a service to persist data on a page refresh.

If the data is large use a database, else use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

**Storing the data**:

```
window.localStorage['data'] = JSON.stringify(data);
```

**Retrieving the data**:

```
return angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['data']);
```

Comment: So if I only want to store a single post, how would I do that using localStorage? I tried saving it to $window.localStore.post = <post> but whenever I attempted to retrieve it it returned [object Object].

Comment: See my edited answer. You'll have to stringify it while storing and convert back to json while fetching.

Comment: There are several localStorage libraries that are designed to work with angular. If you just want to work with localStorage, it's probably safer to go with one of those. Be aware that if you try to put too much in localStorage it will crash iOs.

Comment: yes, but in this case the data size is hardly a problem. Also, I am curious as to why would we need libraries for working with localStorage?

Comment: @TarunDugar Okay, storing the data is working correctly, and when I do console.log(angular.fromJson(window.localStorage['data']) it shows me the correct data, but if I try to save it to a variable, the variable console.logs to [object Object]. Any ideas?

Comment: show the statement where you are assigning to a variable.

Comment: @TarunDugar
vm.thisPost = getPost();

function getPost(){
  return angular.fromJson($window.localStorage['currentPost']);
}

Comment: I think it should work. Can you replicate the problem in a plunker or fiddle?

Comment: They handle things like falling back to cookies if localStorage is not supported, for example, Also, they, oh, I don't know, handle changing objects to JSON for you.

Comment: Ok, I'll surely check them out. Thanks!

Comment: I needed to push it into vm.thisPost instead of assign it to it. Thanks for all your help!