# On refresh of page value of an object is setting as null

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working in `angularjs` and i am facing the issue `onreload` of the page. When i refresh the page the object value is set as `null` due to which conditions are failing in the controller.

```
 var limitOrderReqBean = null;
 obj.updateLimitOrderReq = function(limitReqBean) {
     limitOrderReqBean = limitReqBean;
 }
 obj.getLimitOrderReqBean = function() {
     return limitOrderReqBean;
 }
```

This is the code which is used in `cartservice.js`, where `limitOrderReqBean` this is the object used in controller.
Initialized `var limitOrderReqBean = {};` but still `onrefresh` it sets as empty object.

Comment: I don't get your question. The first line sets `limitOrderReqBean` to null. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Initialized the variable

Comment: What should be its value?

Comment: it is an object so either i have initialize as null / empty object.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you change the first line to `var limitOrderReqBean = {}`, it's initialized to an empty object, right? I don't see what you want, or what you think should happen

Comment: issue is when i refresh that time limitOrderReqBean object will have null ..if i wont refresh the page limitOrderReqBean has value in it. If it takes the null value the object which is used in the controller.js will throw error of null in console.

Comment: So the problem is that when you refresh, the you lose everything. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28955560/5015356) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36204281/5015356)